# Nested IF Returning False

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am helping a non-profit-organisation in creating input controls.

The below formula returns correct results, with the exception of the case where `I15 < 0`, where it is returning `FALSE` instead of returning the result as blank (i.e. `""`).

I read other posts in the forum with answers to similar problem, but could not find where I missed a `""`? Please help.

```
=+IF(I15>0,IF(AND(F15="",G15=""),"Please input expense code and program code",
  IF(F15="","Please input expense code",
  IF(G15="","Please put program code",
  IF(B15="","Please input date",
  IF(C15="","Please specify receipt attached as yes or no",
  IF(D15="","Please specify vendor name","")))))))
```

Comment: before the last parenthesis `IF(D15="","Please specify vendor name",""))))))"")`

Comment: Thanks so much , it worked :)

Comment: @Slai, I hate to do this, but, can you post your comment as an answer when you have some time please

Answer (score 1):

When following the logic of a nested expression, it usually helps to expand and indent each nesting level so that you can clearly see the branching:

```
=IF(I15>0,
    IF(AND(F15="",G15=""),
        "Please input expense code and program code",
        IF(F15="",
            "Please input expense code",
            IF(G15="",
                "Please put program code",
                IF(B15="",
                    "Please input date",
                    IF(C15="",
                        "Please specify receipt attached as yes or no",
                        IF(D15="",
                            "Please specify vendor name",
                            ""
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

Here, I've added a comma and empty string before the final closing parenthesis to constitute the `ELSE` argument for the outermost `if` statement.

You also do not require the `+` at the start of the formula.

Comment: A tool like this formula beautifier is a great help ... http://excelformulabeautifier.com/

Comment: @MattClarke, Thanks - that's great!